# find and replace smilar keywords with url parameters

Tags: php, find, preg-replace

i have text and my keywords with url so i want to find smilar keywords and replace them with url .

$text="Didimin, Aydın'ın turistik bir ilçesidir. Didimdeki sahil şeridi ve altınkumdaki plajları ile birlikte akbükteki plajlarda....";

```
$urls=array('didim'=>'didim.html','altınkum'=>'altinkum.html','akbük'=>'akbük.html');

foreach($urls as $k=>$v){
    $text = preg_replace('~'.$k.'(?!(?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*)</a>)~i',
    '<a href="'.$v.'" rel="bookmark"   title="'.$k.'" >$0</a>', $text,1);       
}
echo $text;
```

How can do result like this?

```
<a href="didim.html"  title="didim">Didimin</a>, Aydın'ın turistik bir ilçesidir. Didimdeki sahil şeridi ve <a href="altinkum.html"  title="altınkum">altınkumdaki</a> plajları ile birlikte <a href="akbük.html" title="akbük">akbükteki</a> plajlarda....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$corr = array('didim'=>'didim.html','altınkum'=>'altinkum.html','akbük'=>'akbük.html');
$str = "Didimin, Aydın'ın turistik bir ilçesidir. Didimdeki sahil şeridi ve altınkumdaki plajları ile birlikte akbükteki plajlarda....";

$pattern = '~(?><(a|head|style|script)\b(?>[^<]++|<(?!/\1))*</\1>|<[^>]++>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\pL*('. implode(array_keys($corr), '|') .')\pL*)~ui';

$str = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
       function ($m) use ($corr) {
           return '<a href="' .$corr[strtolower($m[3])] . '">' . $m[2] . '</a>';
       }, $str);

print_r($str);
```

Comment: <a href="didim.html">Didim</a>in  this still cut the smilar keywords must wrap all the keyword like  this <a href="didim.html">Didimin</a>

Comment: one more question how to do only one similar word replacement in this text just replace only Didimin .

Comment: @NurettinAcar: replace `('. implode(array_keys($corr), '|') .')` by `didim`, use `preg_replace` instead of `preg_replace_callback` and replace the function with the string : `'<a href="didim.html">$2</a>'`

Comment: thankyou just i used my code with your patern and its working.